# How to redirect audio from ubuntu 16.04 hosted in cloud server to connected local machine via xRDP

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I have created an Ubuntu 16.04 instance on a cloud server with KDE for user GUI.
I am connected to the machine from my local windows PC, using mstsc. However, when I play any audio content it's not audible.
I have installed the pulseaudio, still no luck yet. 
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was miss configuration on PulseAudio.
Remapped the *.so files in /etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa file to make it work.

`.nofail
.fail
load-module module-augment-properties
load-module module-always-sink
.ifexists /var/lib/xrdp-pulseaudio-installer/module-xrdp-sink.so
load-module /var/lib/xrdp-pulseaudio-installer/module-xrdp-sink.so
.endif
.ifexists /var/lib/xrdp-pulseaudio-installer/module-xrdp-source.so
load-module /var/lib/xrdp-pulseaudio-installer/module-xrdp-source.so
.endif
load-module module-native-protocol-unix`